# Diagram of the peripheral nervous system of different animals?

Tags: neuroscience, reference-request, neuroimaging

Can anyone recommend a good resource (free or paid) for finding detailed images of the nervous systems of various animals?

In particular I am looking for images of the peripheral nervous system of cephalopods such as Octopi or Squids. Ideally I'd prefer images made via some form of medical imaging with radioactive dye, but I will settle for medical illustrations if that's all I can find.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for Biology.SE